# Getting an integer value from dates VBA

Tags: vba, date, integer

I am trying to get a value difference (integer) between the years of 2 different dates in VBA and take also month (for example 2020 - 2019, the result I would want is 1) but my code only give me a date. Any ideas?

```
For i = 2 To PnLD1WS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            
    PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 164).Value = ((((DateSerial(Year(PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 13)), 0, 0) - DateSerial(Year(PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 3)), 0, 0)) * 12) + (DateSerial(0, (Month(PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 13))), 0) - (DateSerial(0, (Month(PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 3))), 0)))))

Next i
```

Comment: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateDiff:

```vb
DateDiff("yyyy", dat1, dat2)
```

With your code:

```vb
...
With PnLD1WS
   .Cells(i, 164).Value = DateDiff("yyyy", .Cells(i, 13), PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 3))
End with
....
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns a date value, not a number of years, for example 2020 diff to 2016 I would want to get 4

Comment: Did you check formatting of the result cell? It should be set to number not to date?

Comment: Yep that was it...thanks again!